# Program showing false positives for Prime Numbers

Tags: java, numbers

After compiling all numbers are showing Prime. Please point out any type of logical errors.

```
int i, num, res;
boolean flag = false;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number for Prime:");
num = sc.nextInt();

for(i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
    res = num % 2;
    if(res == 0) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
    else flag = true;
}
if(flag = true)
    System.out.println("Prime No.");
else
    System.out.println("Not a Prime No.");
```

Comment: Try `flag == true` in your `if` test.

Comment: `res=num%2`??? That cannot possibly work correctly!!! Perhaps you meant `res=num%i`...

Comment: Why do you check flag for true? That means you check if `true == true` or `false == true`. Checking a boolean variable can be done with `if (flag)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: shouldn't that be, `if (flag)`? Why the unnecessary `== true`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 4):

You are using assignment(single `=`) instead of comparison(double `==`) in the following statement:

```
if(flag  = true)
```

which will always return true, change it to

```
if(flag  == true)
```

Also more concise way is simply using

```
if(flag)
```

Comment: or better use `if(flag)`

Comment: if (flag) { } else { }
 --- or --- 
System.out.println( (flag) ? "No Prim" : "Prime" );

Answer (score 0):

Change `flag= true` to `flag == true` OR `flag` in `if` statement

Try,

```
public boolean isPrimeNumber(int number){
   for(int i=2; i<=number/2; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++){    
    res = (num % 2 || num % 3 || num & 5);
    if(res == 0)
        System.out.println("Prime No.");
    else
        System.out.println("Not a Prime No.");
}
```

The answer for this would be:

Prime number are number which divisible by 2, 3, and 5 because they are the LCD that will prove that if any number divided with them and has still remainder it is a Composite number!

Comment: Sry to say you but this concept will not gonna work as 121,169.....this all are not a prime num .......but a according to your programm it will display number as a prime.....

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is you are not testing for prime, you are testing for even.

if(flag), instead of if(flag = true)

You need to test something like (instead of a for loop):

```
if(num % 2 == 0 ||
    num % 3 == 0 ||
    num % 5 == 0 ||
    num % 7 == 0 ||
    num % 11 == 0)
{
    flag=false;
}
else
{
    flag=true;
}
```

Prime numbers have quite a large list.  [There's 168 in 2-1,000]

For efficiency, I'd recommend groups of 5.  This is can speed up the code by doing less checks.

```
if(!flag && num > 12)  // num being 1 less than the next prime to be checked.

{
   if(num % 13 == 0 ||
   num % 17 == 0 ||
   num % 19 == 0 ||
   num % 23 == 0 ||
   num % 29 == 0)
{
    flag=false;
}
else
{
    flag=true;
}
```

You could make an array of prime numbers, and use a loop to walk through the array until A) You find a true result, or 2) The possible prime number is larger than the number being checked.  [I'm not writing that method]

I used: http://www.factmonster.com/math/numbers/prime.html for the list.